# Creating layers with different Z-Axis positions in SpriteKit?

Tags: sprite-kit

[The scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1ZV7.jpg)

I was wondering about creating 
different layers with different Z-Axis values to give more reality like the above picture as it has 
1- The green background then
2- The play ground it self then 
3- The blurred black trees representing the camera depth of field

So, I thought about Creating the green background then the the black ground with more value of zPosition then the blurred stuff scaled up with more zPosition values, but the problem is when camera moves there is no sense of reality of speed of movement for each layer as they all move together respecting the same positions .

Also I thought about using SceneKit instead as it contains full 3D tools , but the scene is 2D and does not seem to need scenekit.

Thanks in advance as the question seemed too complicated.

Comment: In order to achieve that parallax effect you seek, you going to need to move those background layers in different speeds, the further be the slowest.

Comment: Okay, but I am not using moving backgrounds instead the user moves the hero and the camera following the hero . So I am not in control of backgrounds.

Comment: that is not true, even though the camera moves  with the hero, you can still move the backgrounds

Comment: Yes, but just in case that I control the hero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, it is figured now.
The answer is gonna be that I put a method that makes the background moves against the camera movement direction with one half or third the camera speed. 
As an example
If the camera moves 20 pixels to right , all scene layers seems to be moved  20 pixels to left . So I have to move the background about 8 
pixels to right 
So all layers seem to be moved 20 pixels to left except that background moved 12 to left, which is slower.